# Можно ли отвязать аккаунт от ВКонтакте?

Tags: поддержка, stackexchange, аутентификация

Боюсь, что с моей страничкой ВКонтакте что-то произойдет и я потеряю доступ к своему профилю StackExchange. Как можно мне открепиться от ВКонтакте и прикрепиться к самому StackExchange? Возможно ли это?

Comment: А если с аккаунтом Google что-то произойдет?

Comment: @Nick Volynkin, тогда к самому StackExchange :)